# Cannot submit a question with the software-installation tag

Tags: bug

Umm...

[image]

The tags are [backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/backup), [re-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/re-installation), [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation), and [settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/settings).

I should be allowed to submit this.

Comment: I created an FR for this on meta.se https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374846/make-tag-excerpts-show-the-synonyms-excerpt-when-a-tag-is-a-synonym-of-another. It's quite frustrating as it is now.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are trying to submit a synonym of the banned tag.

Perhaps you need to submit a feature request, so the message says *"The 're-installation' tag is not allowed"*.

Comment: I just stumbled on this scenario myself and found it misleading.  It is not clear by the `re-installation` tag description that it is a banned tag.  Perhaps the tag description should be edited.  ...Oh, this isn't a possibility (for me at least).